# Change array through a function parameter

Tags: javascript

I need to change array to a new array created inside a function.

```
function changeArr(a)
{
    a=["hello"];    // don't work
    //a.push("hello");    //works, but the real array pretty big (dont want copy)
}

var arr=[];

changeArr(arr);

console.log(arr); // should echo ["hello"]
```

Comment: I suggest you read about [call by object sharing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/417685)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like all you really want to do is clear the array that is passed into the function, before appending to it:

```
function changeArr(a)
{        
    a.length = 0;      // clear the array here if you don't care about the prev. contents
    a.push("hello");   // this adds to the array that was passed in
}
```

Comment: Since the array is being truncated, you can take advantage of a performance optimisation by setting the first element of the array to "hello" instead of calling a method to do it: `a.length = 0; a[0] = "hello";`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function `changeArr()`, a is only a local variable referencing the array you passed as an argument when calling this function. `a=["hello"]` makes this local variable reference a newly created and different array. This changes does not affect the original array passed in. What you want to do is likely what Miky Dinescu suggested: use the local variable to modify the original array but don't assign/attach anything new to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to completely replace the array, you can use a return value.

```
function changeArr()
{
    return ["hello"];
}

arr = changeArr();
```

If there is a reason you aren't doing this, explain and I'll adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the splice method as such:

```
a.splice(0,a.length,"hello")
```